# ./configure: line 2178 config.log permission denied

Tags: fedora

I want to install a library libevent . I forgot to `su root` and run `./configure` under my user acount `esolve`. Then I notice there are errors after running `make install` with `esolve`.

My `root` can't modify files which are modified by `esolve` (I'm not very clear why, because this computer's Linux OS has been configured by some system/network administrator).

Now I `su root` and run `./configure`, and I get the following error:

```
 ./configure: line 2178 config.log permission denied
```

So where can I find the `config.log` file and remove or modify it?

FYI - my computer: 3.6.10-2.fc16.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running the `./configure` command in a specific directory, I'd expect the `config.log` to be in that location. You can run this command to find the file from that directory:

```
$ find . -name "config.log"
```

If you're accessing a directory that is mounted from another system then root may not have access to do things on this mounted directory. This is typically the case in Linux/UNIX.

You can check by running this command, again run this from the same directory above:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      429G  375G   32G  93% /
```

If you see a path like: `/dev/...` then the directory is part of the local filesystem of the computer, if you see something like these:

```
# windows share mounted locally
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
//remotecomputer/t    22T   12T   10T  55% /remote/t

# linux share mounted locally
$ df -h .
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
cobbler:/cobbler/isos
                       43G   33G  8.3G  80% /cobbler/isos
```

Then the filesystem is being mounted from another computer and shown as part of the local filesystem, even though it technically isn't.

It's in these last 2 cases where root often times doesn't have write permissions to the shared directories.

#### compiling on a remote share

Typically what I would do is run the first 2 steps of the compilation as a non-root user and then switch over to root for the installation step:

*as non-root*

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

*as root*

```
$ make install
```

Assuming that the target for the installation is some local directory to the computer such as `/usr` or `/usr/local`.

Comment: you are right, the directory is mounted from another system. then what can I do if I want to install the library?

Comment: You should be able to run the `./configure` & `make` steps as your non-root account, and then run the `make install` as root. Are you specifying local paths for the `./configure`?